# Generating convex polyhedron from face planes?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Suppose I have lists of normals and points for planes. There's a convex polyhedron whose faces lie on these planes and are bounded by plane intersections. What would be the easiest way to produce an image of this polyhedron (preferably with the vertices known) in *Mathematica*?

I thought of one really ugly way to do it, but I'm looking for something more automated/efficient than:

1. Iterate through all triples of planes looking to see if they have a common intersection point, and throwing those intersection points into a list.
2. Using a *Mathematica* command to strip duplicates from the list.
3. `ListPointPlot3D` to display those points so I can manually decide which should be grouped together in a polygonal face.
4. Using a *Mathematica* command to build the polyhedron from properly oriented lists of vertices for faces.

**Edit:** As requested, here's an example:
Suppose I have

```
normals = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, -2, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}}
```

and

```
pts = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Then I can make a bunch of plane equations with, say

```
Table[Table[
  Dot[normals[[i]], {x, y, z} - pts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
  Dimensions[normals][[1]]}][[j]] == 0, {j, 1, 
  Dimensions[normals][[1]]}]
```

Three of these five planes intersect at a single point at exactly five points (which could be calculated in a number of ways): those in `{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}`. The final result I'd be looking for in this case would be something like

```
Graphics3D[
 Polygon[{{{0, 0, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 
 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
 1}, {-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 
 0}, {1, -1, 0}}}]]
```

Comment: As always, some example data is very helpful. It's probably going to take me a few minutes to come up with a simple and meaningful example to even begin to attempt possible solutions and I'm already bored by that point and move on to something else... The onus is on _you_, the OP, to put forth a minimal example that saves us the trouble.

Comment: Since you can build the Hessian normal form of your planes, turn them into the corresponding inequalities and feed them into `RegionPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @rm-rf, thank you for the comment. I hope the example I've edited in clears things up. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to make this question more accessible.  J.M., are you saying to use the inequalities for "on the side of the plane towards the center" in each case? If so, is there an easy way to do that automatically if I have too many planes to handle manually?

Comment: Something like `And @@ MapThread[#1.({x, y, z} - #2) <= 0 &, {normals, pts}]` then...

Comment: @helopticor For starters, taking up JM's comment, you can change the `==0` to `<0` and do `RegionPlot3D[And @@ pl, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]` where `pl` is the output of your `Table[...]`

Comment: Are your normals oriented, that is, do they consistently point outward? They're not in your example data, but maybe they are in the real data you want to work with. If so, you can do the `RegionPlot3D` thing. If not, dealing with unoriented planes can be quite problematic (see my comment on @whuber's answer).

Comment: There is a [package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/440/) for polytope vertex enumeration, coauthored by Komei Fukuda.

Comment: Or if you want to write your own, a simplistic approach is as follows. Find the "top" vertex (by linear programming). Find the planes that contain it. Follow each edge from intersections of pairs of these planes. That is to say, figure out which of the remaining planes is first hit by each edge. Each such hit gives a new vertex. Keep doing this, maintaining a stack of edges still to be processed. Any time you reach an edge or vertex that was already seen, drop it from further scrutiny. When the stack is emptied you will have located all your vertices.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because (a) `RegionPlot3D` does not render edges well and (b) detailed information about the vertices and faces could be worthwhile, I will offer a solution that finds this information and displays it clearly.  (The first two lines of code produce the region plot, if you just want to stop there; the rest develop the improved solution.)

I am stuck at one thing: it is hard to find an efficient algorithm to determine the proper orientation of the normals. When you're just given a bunch of planes, they partition space into lots of polytopes.  Some of those will be unbounded, so they can be neglected, but potentially there are many bounded polytopes. We could assume exactly one of them contacts every one of the planes nontrivially: this gives a criterion for finding the polytope that is being described. But this description, if carried out naively (*e.g.*, through a brute-force examination) takes $2^N$ operations for $N$ planes, which is highly unsatisfactory except for small problems.

The following solution identifies *a* polytope by finding all mutual intersections of the planes (the "vertices"), then optionally reorienting each normal so that the number of vertices behind it is at least as great as the number of vertices in front of it.  Although this does not always work, it may be of some service.  Otherwise, if all normals are given in the proper (outward) orientations in the input, one can just delete the single line of code that does the re-orientation and get what was intended.

#### Step by step description

I will take you through the procedure step by step; the full listing is at the end.  Begin with the data: parallel arrays of normals and points on the planes they define. The normals need to point constistently outward or inward of the polyhedron.

```
normals = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, -2, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}};
pts = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}};
dataGraphics = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.015], Gray, Point[pts], Black, Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], 
  MapThread[Arrow[{#2, #1 + #2}] &, {normals, pts}]}]
```

[image: Points and normals]

It will be expeditious to exploit *Mathematica's* fast, compact matrix operations.  Anticipating this, I represent each plane $(n_1,n_2,n_3)\cdot(x,y,z) = p$ as the *four*-vector $(-n_1,-n_2,-n_3,p)$:

```
planes = Union[MapThread[Append[-#1, #1.#2] &, {normals, pts}]]
```

At this point we can easily see the polyhedron by means of `RegionPlot`:

```
regionGraphic = RegionPlot3D[Min[planes . {x, y, z, 1}] >= 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.85]]
```

[image: Region plot]

We will eventually need to inspect all mutual intersections, which are obtained by taking planes three at a time:

```
nodes = Union[Append[#, 1] & /@ 
          Quiet[Cases[LinearSolve[Most /@ #, -Last /@ #] & /@ Subsets[planes, {3}], _List]]]
```

> {{-1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}}

`Quiet` suppresses messages when `LinearSolve` finds no intersections.  The reason for appending $1$ to each node is that the oriented distance of a point $(x,y,z)$ from any plane given in the form $(-n_1,-n_2,-n_3,p)$ is proportional to the inner product $(x,y,z,1)\cdot(-n_1,-n_2,-n_3,p)$: this is what made the `RegionPlot` application so easy.

To reorient the normals (which is *optional*) we only have to count the signs of the oriented distances of every node:

```
planes = MapThread[Times, {planes, 2 UnitStep[Total[nodes . #]] - 1 & /@ planes}]
```

> {{-2, 0, -2, 2}, {0, -2, -2, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, -2, 2}, {2, 0, -2, 2}}

The vertices of the polytope, then, are those behind *every* plane, with some allowance for numerical imprecision:

```
vertices = Select[nodes, Chop[Min[planes.#]] >= 0 &];
```

(See the comments concerning this expression.)

The next steps assemble the vertices into faces in a form suitable for a `GraphicsComplex`.  To do this, we first create the vertex-face incidence matrix, once again allowing for some imprecision, and square it to obtain the vertex-vertex adjacency matrix:

```
incidence = SparseArray[Outer[Boole[Chop[#1.#2] == 0] &, vertices, planes, 1]];
adjacency = Map[Boole[# >= 2] & , incidence . incidence\[Transpose], {2}];
```

The adjacency matrix determines the vertex graph:

[image: Vertex graph]

At this point we can exploit *Mathematica's* graph algorithms to tie these vertices into polygons to represent the faces: it's a question of (easily) finding their order around each face.

```
faceNodes = Flatten[Position[# // Normal, 1]] & /@ (incidence\[Transpose]);
faceGraphs = (SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[adjacency[[#, #]]]] & /@ faceNodes);
orderings = First /@ First[FindEulerianCycle[#]] &  /@ faceGraphs;
faces = MapThread[Part, {faceNodes, orderings}]
```

> {{3, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 3}, {1, 4, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}

The display is now easy:

```
polyGraphics = Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[Most /@ vertices, 
  {Opacity[0.5], Polygon[faces], 
   PointSize[0.015], Red, Opacity[1], Point[Range[Length[vertices]]]}]}];
Show[dataGraphics, polyGraphics, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Final]

It works pretty well on more complex convex polytopes, too.  Here's one with 50 facets, found in 5 seconds:

[image: Random polytope]

---

#### Complete code listing

```
polyhedron[normals_, pts_] := 
 Module[{planes, nodes, vertices, incidence, adjacency, faceNodes, 
   faceGraphs, orderings, faces, result},
  planes = Union[MapThread[Append[-#1, #1.#2] &, {normals, pts}]];
  nodes = 
   Union[Append[#, 1] & /@ 
     Quiet[Cases[LinearSolve[Most /@ #, -Last /@ #] & /@ Subsets[planes, {3}], _List]]];
  (* planes = MapThread[Times, {planes, 2 UnitStep[Total[nodes . #]] - 1& /@ planes}];*)
  vertices = Select[nodes, Chop[Min[planes.#]] >= 0 &];
  incidence = SparseArray[Outer[Boole[Chop[#1.#2] == 0] &, vertices, planes, 1]];
  adjacency = Map[Boole[# >= 2] & , incidence . incidence\[Transpose], {2}];
  faceNodes = Flatten[Position[# // Normal, 1]] & /@ (incidence\[Transpose]);
  faceGraphs = (SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[adjacency[[#, #]]]] & /@ faceNodes);
  orderings = First /@ First[FindEulerianCycle[#]] &  /@ faceGraphs;
  faces = MapThread[Part, {faceNodes, orderings}];
  result["vertices"] = Most /@ vertices; result["faces"] = faces;
  result
  ];
dataGraphics = Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.015], Blue, Point[pts], Blue, Arrowheads[Medium], 
  MapThread[Arrow[{#2, #1 + #2}] &, {normals, pts}]}];
p = polyhedron[normals, pts]; vertices = p["vertices"]; faces = p["faces"]; v = Length[vertices];
polyGraphics = Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[vertices, 
 {Opacity[0.5], Polygon[faces], 
  PointSize[0.015], Red, Opacity[1], Point[Range[v]]}]}];
Show[dataGraphics, polyGraphics, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: You attempted to tackle the issue of poor plane orientation and you have a better presentation of the final result. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Your answers are terrific!

Comment: When I try this code on a polyhedron with many faces (up to 50) it often doesn't  find all the vertices and hence doesn't draw all of the faces. Changing options of `Chop` doesn't help. What might be the problem?

Comment: @level1807 I cannot say: as you can see from my example, I had no trouble with $50$ faces. The possible explanations for what you are encountering could range from differences among MMA versions through floating-point errors through some kind of bug in my code.  It could be related to the limitations described in the introduction to this answer. If you want to resolve this you will need to find as simple as possible an example that can be reproduced and then offer it in a new question.  Good luck!

Comment: @whuber thanks for the answer. I found a funny thing, which I don;t know how to explain. If I replace, in the definition of `vertices`, `Chop[Min[planes.#] >= 0]` by `Chop[Min[planes.#]] >= 0`, then all the vertices are found. BTW my polyhedron is convex and all the normals are oriented outwards from the start.

Comment: @level1807 Good catch! Although I haven't tested it, it looks like a bug to me--evidently from a typographical error.  The intention was to to compare the chopped values to zero, not to chop the results of a floating point comparison (which makes little sense anyway). I will go ahead and modify the code in this answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @whuber There is also a little problem in the cases when there are duplicate solutions of `LinearSolve`. So I suggest `vertices = DeleteDuplicates[Select[nodes, Chop[Min[planes.#]] >= 0 &], Chop[Norm[#1 - #2]] == 0 &]`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to everyone for their helpful comments. I think I have patched together a solution that does what I want (using the package @Daniel Lichtblau linked and the ideas in others' comments). I demonstrate it here with the example from my question:

```
Get["C:\\VertexEnum.m"]; (*Change path as appropriate.*)
(*If you don't use semicolons, you may want: 
Off[General::spell];  Off[General::spell1]; 
Off[Syntax::com]; Off[Write::noopen]; *)
normals = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, -2, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}}; 
(*The normals must be outwardly oriented*)
pts = {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}; 
shift = {10, 10, 10};
(*The shift has to be large enough to push the polyhedron into the first octant 
for the package to work, but its actual values don't matter.*)
ds = MapThread[#1.(#2 + shift) &, {normals, pts}]; 
{shiftedvs,activesets} = VertexEnum`VertexEnumeration[normals, ds]; 
vs = MapThread[#1 - shift &, {shiftedvs}]; 
poly = VertexEnum`Polyhedron3D[vs, activesets];
Show[Graphics3D[poly, 
 ListPointPlot3D[vs, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

`vs` is a list of the vertices if needed for other things, `poly` is a list of lists of vertices to represent the faces, and the `Show` command generates something like this: [image: pyramid]

**Edit**: I realized it's better to let the package handle the making of the polyhedron (although possibly the polygons are oriented the wrong way). While something like `RegionPlot3D[
  And @@ MapThread[#1.({x, y, z} - #2) &lt;= 0 &, {normals, pts}], 
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 25]` will technically work to roughly show the polyhedron, the newly-edited above code uses the package to extract the faces exactly.