# Checking if a point is in a convex 3D polyhedron

Tags: computational-geometry, expression-test, intersection, polyhedra

Extending from these questions [How to check if a 3D point is in a planar polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10333/how-to-check-if-a-3d-point-is-in-a-planar-polygon) and [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon).

I'm trying to do this to render specific shapes made up of spheres.

For a sphere it is easy:

```
(* generate a grid of points*)
d = 20;
points = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, {z, -d, d}]~Flatten~2;

(*check if they are inside a spherical shell*)
points2 = Select[points, 8.5 < Norm[#] < 10 &];

(*render the spheres that are inside the spherical shell*)
Graphics3D[{Sphere[#, 0.75]} & /@ points2, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I want to try and do the same rendering for other shapes, for example a pentagonal dipyramid

```
Graphics3D[{Lighter@Lighter@Blue, Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[Thickness[ 0.005]], PolyhedronData["PentagonalDipyramid", "Faces"]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I'm not sure how to check if the points on the grid are with in the polyhedron.

I can access the faces... `PolyhedronData["PentagonalDipyramid", "Faces"]`

Comment: [Generating convex polyhedron from face planes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14582) is closely related because when the planes' normal vectors are consistently oriented, they provide a simple mechanism for determining whether points are inside or outside (as illustrated, for instance, in the code in my answer in that thread: see the argument to the `RegionPlot3D` example there).

Comment: The RedionFunction approach is quite good. In cases where there are many small faces you might instead consider shooting a ray to the outside and counting intersections. For this to be effective you'd need to bin faces in such a way that most never get tested for intersection, that is, only "reasonable contenders" get tested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the *Mathematica* documentation for [`PolyhedronData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolyhedronData.html) (see Coordinate-related properties under "More information")

> `RegionFunction` – pure function giving `True` in the interior of the polyhedron.

```
PolyhedronData["PentagonalDipyramid", "RegionFunction"]
```

As I was playing around with this I noticed the `Select` part was very slow when running on lots of points, but `Compile` sorted that right out

```
d = 0.04;
points = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1, d}, {y, -1, 1, d}, {z, -1, 1, d}]~Flatten~2;

inDipyramidQ = With[{
    rf = PolyhedronData["PentagonalDipyramid", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z]
   },
   Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{x = pt[[1]], y = pt[[2]], z = pt[[3]]}, If[#, 1, 0] &[rf]],
    Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
   ]
  ];

(* 0.0624s versus uncompiled inPyramidQ that I aborted after >1min *)
points2 = Pick[points, inDipyramidQ[points], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Graphics3D[{Sphere[points2, d/2]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I just found that in the documentation right as I saw your answer. I had been looking around for a while. I was reading about ray-casting algorithms and hoping there would be an easier way. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs6dr.png

Comment: for future users do you think you could elaborate your answer into a complete solution?

Comment: @s0rce Yes, got distracted playing around with it :)

Comment: My solution to the `select` slowness was more brute force `Parallelize@Select[points, rf @@ # &]`. You're method is much better.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Feel free.

Comment: @OleksandrR, I'm curious.

Answer (score 8):

**Version 10** approach:

```
d = 0.04;
points = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1, d}, {y, -1, 1, d}, {z, -1, 1, d}] ~Flatten~ 2;
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ PolyhedronData["PentagonalDipyramid"];
rm = RegionMember[region];
```

Select points in the region:

```
pin = Pick[points, rm @ points, True];
```

Visualize:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[pin, d/2]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Pardon me in advance if I am not directly addressing your question.  A point $p$ is in a convex polyhedron if it is "left-of" each of its faces $F$, where "left-of" is defined by the signed volume of $p$. If the polyhedron is triangulated, then $F$ is a triangle, and the key computation is the signed volume of a tetrahedron formed by $F$ and the point $p$.  This is all over the Internet, and in many books, including my own, *[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html)*; that link will lead you to explicit code for this computation.  If $F$ is not a triangle, then it is easily triangulated, and you can proceed as above.

Comment: Joseph, some *Mathematica* implementation would enhance this answer no end. Since you´ve done it already in C, this should be a picnic ;-)